# What is this tree with twisted bark, fern-like leaves and bright red flowers?

Tags: identification, trees, germination

Please help me to identify this tree. You can see the leaves and red flowers in my photos.

I like it and want to seed it. How should I germinate this lovely tree?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please tell us where the tree is that you have photographed.  A closeup image of the bark and flowers would help too.

Comment: What part of the world are these trees located in?  That would help immensely.

Comment: I'm looking at this tree in my backyard in Maui right now. We also have the invasive *albizia julibrissin* (aka Mimosa) here, too, but they have different flowers than this one.

Answer (score 10):

This is a Delonix regia, a tree very similar to more famous Albicia julibrissin, but with entirely different flowers:

[image]

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delonix_regia[image]

On propagation, from [www.thespruce.com](https://www.thespruce.com/royal-poinciana-growing-profile-3269287):

> Seed germination and cuttings are used to propagate this tree. Seeds
>   will need to be sacrificed first to break open the seed coat and allow
>   water to germinate the seed.

There is even an [online comprehensive guide](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/germinate-royal-poinciana-seeds-64977.html) on using Delonix regia's seed for propagation.

Answer (score 2):

The leaves make this tree look like an acacia, and there is an acacia named the red flowering acacia with similar flowers, so google that, @AbdulmajeedFarah, and see if you can find what you are looking for.

Comment: Red flowered acacia is a common name often used by companies selling stock photos - the tree they're showing is usually Delonix regia, or Caesalpinia pulcherrima, not an acacia at all. The true red flowered Acacia leprosa 'Scarlet Blaze' looks nothing like Delonix, even the leaves are dissimilar. For ID purposes, what counts is not the common name, but the botanical or Latin name.